# Total Euclidian length of a vector

Tags: python, numpy, math, euclidean-distance

Given a set of vectors points, what is an efficient way of computing total Euclidian length (sum of Euclidian thenthes between all points). I think about:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 4]])
length = np.diag(cdist(a, a), 1).sum()
```

Is there something more elegant?

Comment: do you mean the total vector length, or the distance between all points? For the latter, you would compute a distance matrix, set the lower or upper triangle to zero and sum up the rest.

Comment: total vector length Euc(p2 - p1) +  Euc(p3 - p2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Euc(p2-p1)+Euc(p3-p2)` is what you are after, your approach is not correct. You are looking for:

```
length = np.sqrt( ((a[1:]-a[:-1])**2).sum(-1)).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pdist`, which only keeps the upper triangle natively

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 4]])
length = pdist(a).sum()
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion in the comment total 3 points vector length is :  Euc(p2 - p1) +  Euc(p3 - p2) without Euc(p3 - p1) so the triangle will contain more items